# Help syntax for a dos command

Tags: batch-file, dos

I'm looking for a reference regarding the syntax of the help displayed for a dos command.

I didn't find anything with Google.

I need this because I'm writing a batch and I want to provide help for this batch regarding arguments and options.

I know I could deduce it from the help of existing dos commands, but it would be great if there was a full reference about it.

Comment: Note that `cmd` is not DOS. I chose not to delete those references since what you're asking *also* applies to DOS. Still, the Windows Command Processor only shares tiny bits of syntax and idiosyncrasies with DOS. And perhaps the gray-text-on-black color scheme.

Comment: @Jérôme you mean something like this i suppose: [command help](http://ss64.com/nt/tracert.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean the syntax as in the following?

```
findstr [/b] [/e] [/l] [/r] [/s] [/i] [/x] [/v] [/n] [/m] [/o] [/p] [/offline] [/g:file] [/f:file] [/c:string] [/d:dirlist] [/a:ColorAttribute] [strings] [[Drive:][Path] FileName [...]]
```

That's easy. Things in square brackets can be omitted. The `[...]` at the end indicates that you can supply more files if you wish, it doesn't have to be just one.

There are also alternatives sometimes:

```
attrib [{+r|-r}] [{+a|-a}] [{+s|-s}] [{+h|-h}] [[Drive:][Path] FileName] [/s[/d]]
```

indicated by curly braces while alternatives are separated by `|`. Also noteworthy here: `/d` at the end is only valid if you also provided `/s` since there are two nested levels of brackets.

There is no strict syntax definition and you can usually figure out some other aspects, like the `[...]` on your own. Many examples need a bit interpretation (which mostly is obvious, though). E.g. `date`:

```
date [mm-dd-yy] [/t]
```

You can supply a date in a weird format as the first argument, but that's very easy to guess. And no, it doesn't tell you to supply literally `mm-dd-yy`, but that's why humans read that description, not machines.

---

**EDIT:** I just noticed that Technet even gives a summary of the syntax at the bottom of each article:

[image: Technet syntax summary]